# JSF datatable line switching to editable on checkbox click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, render, jsf-2.2

Ok so i have a data table that is supposed to be an admin page for a book store. I have got everything working on it except i am supposed to have a check box on each row that will switch the outputs to inputs and let you edit a book in the table

i have confirmed through the console that it is running the method and setting the boolean value to true, but it is not re rendering the row to be editable. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still very new to JSF

My index page

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>                

        <h1>Administrator Page</h1>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <h:dataTable value="#{bookDatabase.books}"
                         rowClasses="evenRow,oddRow"
                         id="edit"
                         var="book">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">edit</f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{book.editable}"
                                             onclick="submit()"/>

                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{book.title}" 
                                 rendered="#{book.editable}" size="10"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" 
                                  rendered="#{not book.editable}"/>

                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Author</f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{book.author}" 
                                 rendered="#{book.editable}" size="10"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.author}" 
                                  rendered="#{not book.editable}"/>

                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText id="unitPrice2" value="#{book.price}"
                                  rendered="#{not book.editable}">
                        <f:convertNumber    currencyCode="USD"  type="currency" />
                    </h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText id="unitPrice" value="#{book.price}"
                                 rendered="#{book.editable}" size="10">
                        <f:convertNumber    currencyCode="USD"  type="currency" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandLink value="Delete" 
                                   action="#{bookDatabase.removeBook(book.title)}"/>
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>

            <br></br>
        Title: <h:inputText  id="title" value="#{bookDatabase.title}"/> <br></br>
        Author: <h:inputText  id="author" value="#{bookDatabase.author}"/> <br></br>
        Price: <h:inputText  id="price" value="#{bookDatabase.price}"/> <br></br>
        <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{bookDatabase.addBook()}"/>
        <br></br>

    </h:form>


</h:body>
```

The book class

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

public class Book implements Serializable {
String title;
String author;
double price;
String orderNumeber;
int quan;
double sub;
double total;
boolean editable;

public Book(String title, String author, double price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
}

Book() {
    title = null;
    author = null;
    price = 0.0;
    orderNumeber = "";
    quan = 0;
    sub = 0.0;
    total = 0.0;
    editable = false;

}

public String editableCheck(String title) {
    System.out.print(title);
    if (this.title.equals(title)) {

        if (editable == true) {
            editable = false;
        } else {
            editable = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(editable);
    return null;
}

public boolean isEditable() {

    return editable;
}

public void setEditable(boolean editable) {

    this.editable = editable;
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(double total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public int getQuan() {
    return quan;
}

public void setQuan(int quan) {
    this.quan = quan;
}

public double getSub() {
    return sub;
}

public void setSub(double sub) {
    this.sub = sub;
}

public String getOrderNumeber() {
    return orderNumeber;
}

public void setOrderNumeber(String orderNumeber) {
    this.orderNumeber = orderNumeber;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

I dont think my bookDatabase class has any affect on it but here it is just in case

```
 @Named(value = "bookDatabase")
@SessionScoped
public class BookDatabase implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of BookDatabase
     */
    private List<Book> books;
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/database2")
    private DataSource ds;

    private boolean display;
    private boolean edit;
private boolean add;
private boolean remove;
private String title;
private String author;
private String price;
private String bookToRemove;
Book addBook;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    books = new ArrayList<>();
    display = false;
    edit = false;
    add = false;
    remove = false;
    addBook = new Book();
    title = null;
    author = null;
    price = null;
    bookToRemove= null;

}

public String getBookToRemove() {
    return bookToRemove;
}

public void setBookToRemove(String bookToRemove) {
    this.bookToRemove = bookToRemove;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public void removeBook() throws SQLException
{
    if (ds == null) {
        throw new SQLException("ds is null; Can't get data source");
    }

    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    if (conn == null) {
        throw new SQLException("conn is null; Can't get db connection");
    }
    try {
        System.out.print(bookToRemove);
        PreparedStatement ord = conn.prepareStatement("Delete from APP.BOOK where Title = ?");
        ord.setString(1, bookToRemove);

        ord.execute();
        bookToRemove = null;

    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }

}
public void removeBook(String toRemove) throws SQLException
{
    bookToRemove = toRemove;
    removeBook();
}



public void addBook() throws SQLException {

    if (ds == null) {
        throw new SQLException("ds is null; Can't get data source");
    }

    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    if (conn == null) {
        throw new SQLException("conn is null; Can't get db connection");
    }
    try {
        if(author != null && title != null)
        {


        PreparedStatement ord = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO APP.BOOK (TITLE, AUTHOR, PRICE) "
                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        ord.setString(1, title);
        ord.setString(2, author);
        ord.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble(price));


        ord.execute();
        author = null;
        title=null;
        price  = null;
        }
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }

}

public void renderDisplay() {
    display = true;
    edit = false;
    add = false;
    remove = false;

}

public void renderEdit() {
    display = false;
    edit = true;
    add = false;
    remove = false;

}

public void renderAdd() {
    display = false;
    edit = false;
    add = true;
    remove = false;

}

public void renderRemove() {
    display = false;
    edit = false;
    add = false;
    remove = true;

}

public boolean isDisplay() {
    return display;
}

public void setDisplay(boolean display) {
    this.display = display;
}

public boolean isEdit() {
    return edit;
}

public void setEdit(boolean edit) {
    this.edit = edit;
}

public boolean isAdd() {
    return add;
}

public void setAdd(boolean add) {
    this.add = add;
}

public boolean isRemove() {
    return remove;
}

public void setRemove(boolean remove) {
    this.remove = remove;
}

public List<Book> getBooks() throws SQLException {
    books.clear();

    if (ds == null) {
        throw new SQLException("ds is null; Can't get data source");
    }

    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    if (conn == null) {
        throw new SQLException("conn is null; Can't get db connection");
    }

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                "select TITLE, AUTHOR, PRICE from BOOK"
        );

        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
            Book b = new Book();
            b.setAuthor(result.getString("AUTHOR"));
            b.setTitle(result.getString("TITLE"));
            b.setPrice(result.getDouble("PRICE"));
            books.add(b);
        }
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }

    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}

public String getSpecificTitle(int number) {
    Book currentBook = (Book) books.get(number);
    return currentBook.getTitle();

}

public String getSpecificAuthor(int number) {
    Book currentBook = (Book) books.get(number);
    return currentBook.getAuthor();

}

public double getSpecificPrice(int number) {
    Book currentBook = (Book) books.get(number);
    return currentBook.getPrice();



   }

}
```

Again thank you so much for any help you may be able to give me

Comment: Just one side note : You placed critical business logic inside an accessor method `getBooks()` (being referred to through `<h:dataTable value="#{bookDatabase.books}"...>`). This method is invoked several times by nature. Consider moving its code, for example, in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. A session scoped bean in such a scenario should not be needed. A view scoped bean should be sufficient (You are using JSF 2.2/Java EE 7 (I avoided the `[jsf-2]` tag) where `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` (CDI) is available). Perhaps, you are targeting to old EOL JSF 1.x tutorials/books somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK folks i have figured out my issue. i was clearing the array of books everytime i called get books in bookDatabase

```
public List<Book> getBooks() throws SQLException {
books.clear();
```

I changed this to an if check to see if the array was empty and it now works.

Tiny i also took your advise and moved my logic out of the get method for books. thank you for your help. I am slowly but surly getting better at JSF.